# How to generate the openapi.json with nswag

Tags: json, openapi, nswag

I am using nswag to generate the swagger. However the openapi json file is only in memory, you can only access it by starting the application and navigate to the link swagger/v1/swagger.json.

I want the json file to be generated and save physically in the project after every build.
How should I achieved this?

Answer (score 1):

Create an `nswag.json` configuration file in root of project, and specify in it e.g. `"output": "swagger.json"`.
See documentation of `nswag.json` here: https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/wiki/NSwag-Configuration-Document

Then add something like this to your `.csproj` file to have it run on building the project:

```
<Target Name="NSwag" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(ProjectDir)" EnvironmentVariables="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development" Command="$(NSwagExe_Net60) run nswag.json /variables:Configuration=$(Configuration)" />
</Target>
```

See documentation here: https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/wiki/NSwag.MSBuild